# Powershell Array of Hashtable

Tags: powershell

How do you pass some data from parameter to an Array of Hashtable?

```
filnemane.ps1 -param @{ a = 1, b = 2, c =3}, @{ a = 4, b = 5, c =6}
```

to this output:

```
$param = @(
           @{
             a=1,
             b=2,
             c=3
            },
           @{
             a=4,
             b=5,
             c=6
            }
          )
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not understanding the "to this output" part because a parameter is still input.  But the `=` in `-param = @{ ... }` is invalid.  Otherwise, you want your script to create a hashtable of hashtables?  With what keys?  Or you want the hashtables to be combined before the script even receives them?

Comment: @BACON oops sorry, did some typo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You declare a parameter to be of type `[hashtable[]]` (that is, an array of `[hashtable]`'s):

```
# filename.ps1
param(
    [hashtable[]]$Hashtables
)

Write-Host "Hashtables: @("
foreach($hashtable in $Hashtables){
    Write-Host "  @{"
    foreach($entry in $hashtable.GetEnumerator()){
        Write-Host "    " $entry.Key = $entry.Value
    }
    Write-Host "  }"
}
Write-Host ")"
```

With you're sample input you'd get something like:

```
PS C:\> .\filename.ps1 -Hashtables @{ a = 1; b = 2; c =3},@{ a = 4; b = 5; c =6}
Hashtables: @(
  @{
     c = 3
     b = 2
     a = 1
  }
  @{
     c = 6
     b = 5
     a = 4
  }
)
```

Notice that the output won't necessarily retain the key order from the input, because, well, that's not how hash tables work :)

---

As [Matthew helpfully points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287601/powershell-array-of-hashtable/60287749?noredirect=1#comment106641685_60287749), if maintaining the key order is important, go with an ordered dictionary instead (`[ordered]@{}`).

To support accepting either kind without messing up the key order, declare the parameter type as an array of `[System.Collections.IDictionary]` - an interface that both types implement:

```
param(
    [System.Collections.IDictionary[]]$Hashtables
)
```

Comment: Adding on to this, if you want to retain the order, you can declare the parameter as `[ordered[]]` which makes an ordered dictionary object and which functions similarly to a `[hashtable]`, but retains the order you entered your data.

Comment: Sorry, to array variable but I tried this not sure why the output is just 

Hashtables: @(
)

Comment: @TenUy inside the script, `$Hashtables` is _already_ an array variable! You can replace my code with whatever you need. Try `$hashtables[0]` for example